# Unable to import using Wizard or Loadder

Tags: data

can i import data using wizard or loadder  without matching id,name,email to account or contact? or can you suggest option to do so other way

I am trying to import account from csv having name,website and phone as coloumns

currently i have no account or contact records in my org...and i have a csv having three coloumns name,website and phone..i tried to use import wizard for accounts and contacts but i am unable to import it..can this be done in other way

Comment: can you give us more details on what you are trying to do ? do you have any existing data file to import ? what fields / columns you have in the file ?

Comment: Thanks Vamsi, I am trying to import account from csv having name,website and phone as coloumns..can it be done?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Vignesh..currently i have no account or contact records in my org...and i have a csv having three coloumns name,website and phone..i tried to use import wizard for accounts and contacts but i am unable to import it..can this be done in other way..

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to insert(import) data into account and contact  object  right ? then what will be error show ?
 I think you have to use **ApexData Loder** or Inbuild **Data Import wizard**

**Data management** --> **Select Data Import Wizard**  using that you have to import your data file. If you do not mapping field than you have to write proper naming convention in CSV file according to object field Like **AccountName** instead of **Name** then wizard automatically mapping. 
[image]

Then checkout in mapping list all field are proper or not.In that case Phone field is also in **Contact** Object & in Contact object **Last Name** is required field than it will give Error.So you have insert LastName also otherwise if you have insert data in only account object then remove mapping of **Contact:phone** just uncheck that field.

If i am wrong then please correct me.I hope this might be useful for you.

Comment: thanks for your intrest.. currently i have no accounts and contacts...pls consider this situation

Comment: Yes @Krishna using this way you have insert new records in account and contact object.